# How to use a stylus variable in a selector

Tags: stylus

I would like to do something like this:

```
for $num in (1..100)
  :scope[md="$num"]
    width: $num + '%'
```

but it gives me this

```
:scope[md="$num"] {
  width: 1%;
}
:scope[md="$num"] {
  width: 2%;
}
```

How can I make $num be replaced in the selector as well?

Comment: Not sure (thus commenting) since I'm far from being a knowledgeable stylus user, but have you tried interpolation?, e.g.: `:scope[md="{$num}"]` ?

Comment: Thanks for trying but this didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use interpolation. In the comment Jcl has made a little mistake by not remove the quotes:

**STYLUS**

```
for $num in (1..100)
  :scope[md={$num}]
    width: $num + '%'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
:scope[md=1] {
  width: 1%;
}
:scope[md=2] {
  width: 2%;
}
:scope[md=3] {
  width: 3%;
}
...
```

If you want the output with quotes you can escape like this:

```
:scope[md=\"{$num}\"]
```